# Modular arithmetic with lists

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic

> Given a list $[1,2,\dots,n]$ if you at each step take the two first elements and move them to the end of the list such that you flip the order, what is the first element of the list after $k$ steps?

For $n = 3$ the result is just $[1,2,3] \to [3,2,1] \to [1,2,3]$ so this cycles with $1$ step.

I tried to see some patterns here and for $n = 4$ I found that the first elements are $1,3,2,4,1,3,2,4$ i.e. it's cyclic after $4$ steps.

For $n = 5$ the first elements are $1,3,5,1,3,5, \dots$ i.e. it's cyclic after $3$ steps.

So I'm led to believe there is some modulo trick that I could use to solve the problem, but the patterns seem pretty random. Is it possible to draw some conclusion from these?

Comment: Are you familiar with permutations?  Can you describe your process with the language of permutations?  Recognize how the even case and the odd case differ.  Consider the disjoint cyclic decomposition of your permutation.  "*But the pattern seems pretty random*"  The pattern is actually quite straightforward.  Cycle through the odd numbers in increasing order.  If $n$ odd, when done then cycle through the odd numbers in increasing order again ad infinitum.  Otherwise if $n$ even then after cycling through the odds in increasing order, cycle through the evens.  After the evens then repeat.

Comment: So, for $n=100$ the first entries follow the sequence $1,3,5,7,\dots,99,2,4,6,\dots,98,100,1,3,5,\dots$ and meanwhile for $n=99$ the first entries follow the sequence $1,3,5,7,\dots,97,99,1,3,5,7,\dots,97,99,1,\dots$

Comment: I'm not sure I understood how this could be done with permutations or the cycle representation. I would think that there is a closed form for this? @JMoravitz

Comment: 123 321 123 2 steps

1234 3421 2143 4312 1234 4 steps
12345 34521 52143 14325 32541 54123 123 45 6 steps

12345 34521 52143 14325 32541 54123 12345 6 steps 

123456 345621 562143 214365 436512 651234 123456 6 steps

1234567 3456721 5672143 7214365 1436527 3652741 5274163 7416325 1632547 3254761 5476123 7612345 1234567 12 steps. 

12345678 34567821 56782143 78214365 21436587 43658712 65871234 87123456 12345678 8 steps. 

First pattern is, the number of steps to full circle is always n steps for even n .